# Difference between Type(f)(Type) and Type(*f)(Type) for function pointers?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

What is the difference between these two function prototypes ?

```
void apply1(double(f)(double));
void apply2(double(*f)(double));
```

If the goal is to apply the provided function to an array, is there a version faster compared to the other one ?

EDIT :
An example of implementation :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

// First version
template<typename Type> void apply1(std::vector<Type>& v, Type(f)(Type))
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        v[i] = f(v[i]);
    }
}

// Second version
template<typename Type> void apply2(std::vector<Type>& v, Type(*f)(Type))
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        v[i] = f(v[i]);
    }
}

// Main
int main()
{
   std::vector<double> v = {1., 2., 3., 4., 5.};
   apply1(v, std::sin);
   apply2(v, std::sin);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now your function declarations do not match the definitions. You are leaving out the std::vector argument. The second declaration is the only one with a valid function pointer.

Comment: [function pointers](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html)

Comment: Ok, so why the first version compiles in the example ?

Comment: A function point is a function pointer, so there probably won't be any difference in speed. Unless you *have* to write your own, just use: `std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), sin);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the speed of the template wrapper instantiation is going to be almost entirely at the mercy of your optimizer.

That said, I've reduced your samples to the most basic code I can think of, specifically to check the invoke of the function parameters. You can read on, but you'll see they invoke exactly the same. There is no benefit for one declaration vs another. Further, I included the one you left out, (reference-decl)

```
#include <cstdio>

int hello(int x)
{
    return x;
}

template<typename Type> 
void apply1(Type x, Type (f)(Type))
{
    f(x);
}

template<typename Type> 
void apply2(Type x, Type (*f)(Type))
{
    f(x);
}

template<typename Type> 
void apply3(Type x, Type (&f)(Type))
{
    f(x);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    apply1(1,hello);
    apply2(2,hello);
    apply3(3,hello);
    return 0;
}
```

The actual asm generated from the deductions is:

**apply1**

```
__Z6apply1IiEvT_PFS0_S0_E:
Leh_func_begin2:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp2:
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp3:
    subq    $16, %rsp
Ltmp4:
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
    movl    -4(%rbp), %ecx
    movl    %ecx, %edi
    callq   *%rax
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
Leh_func_end2:
```

**apply2**

```
__Z6apply2IiEvT_PFS0_S0_E:
Leh_func_begin3:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp5:
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp6:
    subq    $16, %rsp
Ltmp7:
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
    movl    -4(%rbp), %ecx
    movl    %ecx, %edi
    callq   *%rax
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
Leh_func_end3:
```

**apply3**

```
__Z6apply3IiEvT_RFS0_S0_E:
Leh_func_begin4:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp8:
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp9:
    subq    $16, %rsp
Ltmp10:
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
    movl    -4(%rbp), %ecx
    movl    %ecx, %edi
    callq   *%rax
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
Leh_func_end4:
```

They are **identical** (as I suspected they would be). There is no difference that I can see *whatsoever*.

Note: it is worth mentioning the way the compiler *saw* these declarations by name mangling examination:

```
apply1: __Z6apply1IiEvT_PFS0_S0_E
apply2: __Z6apply2IiEvT_PFS0_S0_E
apply3: __Z6apply3IiEvT_RFS0_S0_E
```

Answer (score 5):

```
void apply1(double(f)(double));
void apply2(double(*f)(double));
```

These two functions have identical signatures so there should be no difference. They both take a pointer to function parameter.

ISO/IEC 14882:2011 8.3.5 [dcl.fct] / 5:

> After determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type "array of T" or "function returning T" is adjusted to be "pointer to T" or "pointer to function returning T," respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to keep it more simple to you.Lets say there is a small program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void my_int_func(int x)
{
    printf( "%d\n", x );
}

int main()
{
    void (*foo)(int);
    // the ampersand is actually optional
    foo = &my_int_func;

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see above there is a function which takes an integer and returns a void.
inside main i am initializing a function pointer foo with my_int_func.And please see carefully the comment "the ampersand is an optional".
Actually it says all.there is no difference in initializing with an an ampersand and without an ampersand.

so there is no difference in both of your statements.

Comment: A side note: the address-of operator (ampersand) is often considered better style when dealing with function pointers, because when you use &func it becomes clearer to the reader that you are assigning a function pointer, rather than just taking the result of a called function. But more importantly, it keeps the language notation coherent, as you would treat pointers to objects and pointers to function in the same manner, syntax-wise.